# SQLite Group by Month

Tags: sqlite, date, group-by

I am using SQLite Database and in one my table has field purchased_date (TEXT ,since DATE is not in SQLLite)

Now I want to run query that return me all the results where user purchased in Month of February 2012

I am storing Dates in following format

```
Tue Mar 27 09:38:31 BST 2012
```

Is it possible to run query for above date format or do I need to put in different format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the strftime built-in function to extract the month from the stored text value and group by this.

A full list of the datetime functions can be found here http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: can you please post the table structure and sql statement you use?

Comment: Its sorted ... To getstrftime work date format should be "YYYY-MM-DD" . I updated by table to have this format and it worked. Thanks for the reply...